# Importing animated .3DS max file into unity3D

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animated .3ds max file. I have imported the file in unity3D. The animation works in preview of animation tab in bottom right corner of the image, have attached the screen shot of it. But, while i play the scene, It comes with a blank scene, i am not able to see man and the animation. Cant able to find the solution for it. Please help me to fix the issue.
Reference screenshot is placed in the below link
https://www.hightail.com/download/OGhlYnU3TERCTWxMWE1UQw
https://www.hightail.com/download/OGhjeFlTSWVUME5qQTlVag

Comment: Is the model present in the scene? Does it have a valid material?

Comment: ya it is present in the scene. please see the attached link

Comment: Showing the human at the right location is fixed now. The human is visible at the Unity and iOS app front. Now, the only issue is, the human is not animating on the iOS app. When i checked at Unity, the human animation is not playing when clicking on game Play button, however i could able to see the same animation at the 'preview' placed at the bottom of the Unity screen. Please advise, how to play the animation in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your object is visible by your camera. Select your camera in objects list and you will see small preview.

Comment: ya i have set the camera...have updated my question with another image with have camera preview....problem is with animation...man is not animating

Comment: Showing the human at the right location is fixed now. The human is visible at the Unity and iOS app front. Now, the only issue is, the human is not animating on the iOS app. When i checked at Unity, the human animation is not playing when clicking on game Play button, however i could able to see the same animation at the 'preview' placed at the bottom of the Unity screen. Please advise, how to play the animation in Unity.